# Create Android phone web server behind NAT using UDP Hole punch

Tags: android, mobile, udp, hole-punching

I"m new in Android development. I"m trying to create app that will run in the background as server and will serve JSON data or simple string, and any client could send command and get back that data regarding the command, similar to web server.

I created simple clients server applications where I've tried to use NAT Traversal technique that punches a hole in router and sending the port and IP to the external Server that manages all the connections, and it worked, but it is very unreliable, at least for someone that never experienced in server client communication development.

My question are:

Is it the right solution to use UDP hole punch technique? is there any working examples?
Is there any alternatives to get data from mobile by request behind the routers without dealing with router port forwarding ?
Are there any existing android native services that running or could run?

Thank you.